# Turn on package-check-signature and install ELPA packages on Mac OS X Emacs

Tags: package, osx

I had my GUI emacs installed by `brew cask install emacs`.

I wanted to strictly check the downloaded package, by its signature, so I put following (as for testing, solely) in `~/.emacs.d/init.el`:

```
(require 'package)
(setq package-check-signature t)
```

When try to install any package (from elpa) by the package interface of `M-x list-packages`, it results in message of `epg-context--make: GPG error: "no usable configuration", OpenPGP`, and cannot install.

#### Question

- How can I configure the `init.el` so that I can turn on `package-check-signature` and install packages?

#### Env

- GNU Emacs 25.3.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0, NS appkit-1265.21 Version 10.9.5 (Build 13F1911))
- OS X El Capitan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that, I needed to install OpenGPG separately.

```
brew install gnupg
```

solved this problem.